# How to change the radius of the circle around the marker in Google Map API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am trying to change the circle radius  by changing the value of combo-menu. So I wrote the a function for onchange as below.

```
    function changeRadius(){ 
       var selectedRadius = (document.getElementById("circle_radius").value)*1000;

       var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              map: map,
              radius: selectedRadius // radius unit is meter.
            });

       var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(40,-90),
              draggable: true,
              title: 'Drag me!'
            });

       circle1.bindTo('center', marker2, 'position'); 

   }
```

But It doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: google maps api documentation doesn't state any bindTo() function for circle, is it your own function, what does it do?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095118/interactive-circle-in-google-map-which-changes-on-changing-radius , and the answer you want is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095490/1290746

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
   document.getElementById('circle_radius'), 'change', function() {
       circle.setRadius(document.getElementById('circle_radius').value)
   });
```

with this function you'll set up a function as listener for the circle_radius combo value change event. The function will update the radius of your circle with the value of the combo.