# How to clear previous circle from map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i need to clear the previous circle before adding a new one .
This is a part of my js code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-distance').change(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");
        var value =  parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
             map: map,
             radius: value,
             fillColor: '#337ab7'
        });
        //circle.setMap(null);
        circle.bindTo('center', markerc, 'position');
        document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", find_closest_marker(value));  
    });
});
```

Comment: put `circle.setMap(null);` before `var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095118/interactive-circle-in-google-map-which-changes-on-changing-radius

Comment: no circle shown !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reuse circle variable.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        map: map,
                        radius: // PUT HERE INITIAL VALUE OR 0,
                        fillColor: '#337ab7'
                    });
$(document).ready(function() {                      
                   $('#select-distance').change(function() {
                    var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");
                    var value =  parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

                    circle.setRadius(value);
                    circle.bindTo('center', markerc, 'position');
                    document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", find_closest_marker(value));  

                  });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var circle; //circle global object
$(document).ready(function() {
if(typeof circle == "object") //check circle is present on map
{
 circle.setMap(null);
}
$('#select-distance').change(function() {
var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");
var value =  parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

circle = new google.maps.Circle({
map: map,
radius: value,
fillColor: '#337ab7'
});
//circle.setMap(null);
circle.bindTo('center', markerc, 'position');
document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", find_closest_marker(value));  

});
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: circle is not defined !!

Comment: @ KARAN LAGALWAR i checked the answer thnx a lot